# How submit macOS screensaver(.saver file) to Appstore?

Tags: macos, app-store, submit, screensaver, notarize

I created a mac screensaver & I'm able to test it with archiving it & installing the '.saver' file.

But how can I submit this '.saver' file to Appstore?
The 'Transporter' app is not accepting it.

I could't find any tutorial about it.

I have 2 targets in my project, the default one is that I mentioned above, another one can run on my mac directly from Xcode as an app.
I'm not sure about submitting this one, What if it didn't placed on user's mac screensavers window...?

Because when I run this on my mac, it runs as a normal mac application in a window!

**Update**

OK, I submitted it on the Appstore and it approved! but, as I expected, it installs like a normal macOS app & doesn't appear on screensavers list.

**how can I submit this '.saver' file to Appstore?**

**Update 2**

I researched a lot about it and found out as 'Max' said on comments, its not an app and should not be on the Appstore itself, we should build and app to copy 'screensaver.saver' file in to it, and then copy the screensaver file to user system, or run it from user OSX so it will install automatically.

Now the real deal and the huge problem and the mother of all headaches appear here!
The Notarization Process!

Now if a user install our screensaver & everything works fine, still the screensaver will not run, and user will see a message like this when he/she wants to run it:

[image]

OK, now we need to notarize our 'screensaver.saver' file to fix this.

I tried very hard to do that, but I failed, because of its complicated process... and because all of them was about PKG & DMG files.

But I'll put the references here to help others, Please help yourself & if you found out how to do it right, post an answer here & help other non professional developers who can't speak Alien languages...

[Awesome explanation #1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53121755/6449292)

[Awesome explanation #2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56890758/6449292)

[Awesome explanation #3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56307714/how-to-properly-codesign-macos-screensaver)

[Some related question that might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29375013/why-is-a-fresh-mac-not-displaying-my-screen-saver)

Cheers!

Comment: You can't. You will need to develop your own program to install the screen saver. It's not possible to distribute *.saver files through the Mac App Store.

Comment: @Max do you have any tutorial for that?

Comment: Nope, but Google might help.

Comment: This process may no longer work. Apple rejected my app due to Guideline 2.4.5(ii). It states that apps “cannot install code or resources in shared locations”. Specifically, they said my app attempts to install a screensaver and asked me to remove that functionality. My app just opens the .saver on init, then exits. If there’s another method, I’d love to hear it.

Comment: Well, I gave up developing screensavers... it seems Apple doesn't want us to create screensavers...